# Show that $P(X>\theta \mathbb{E}X) \geq (1-\theta)^2\frac{(\mathbb{E}X)^2}{\mathbb{E} X^2} $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Consider a random variable $X$ that satisfies $X\geq 0\text{ a.s.}$ and $\text{Var}X<\infty$. Suppose that $0\leq \theta\leq 1$ Then show that $$P(X>\theta \mathbb{E}X)
\geq (1-\theta)^2\frac{(\mathbb{E}X)^2}{\mathbb{E} X^2} $$

I tried the following chain of inequalities but it didn't work:\begin{align}
P(X>\theta \mathbb{E}X)= P(X-\mathbb{E}X>(\theta-1)\mathbb{E}X)\\
=1-P(X-\mathbb{E}X\leq (\theta-1)\mathbb{E}X)\\
=1-P(\mathbb{E}X-X\ge (1-\theta)\mathbb{E}X)\\
\geq 1-P(|\mathbb{E}X-X|\ge (1-\theta)\mathbb{E}X)\\
\geq 1-\frac{\text{Var}X}{(1-\theta)^2(EX)^2}\end{align}
Where in the last point I used Chebyshev's inequality, and previously markov's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X - \theta\mathbb EX \leq X \mathbf 1_{X > \theta \mathbb EX}$, almost surely. Therefore, seeing that $$0 \leq \mathbb E[X - \theta \mathbb EX] \leq \mathbb E[X \mathbf 1_{X > \theta \mathbb E X}]$$ the Cauchy Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
\mathbb E[X - \theta \mathbb EX]^2 \leq \mathbb E[X \mathbf 1_{X > \theta \mathbb E X}]^2 \leq \mathbb E[X^2]\mathbb E[1_{X > \theta \mathbb E X}]^2 = \mathbb E[X^2] P(X > \theta \mathbb E X) \\ \implies P(X > \theta \mathbb  EX) \geq \frac{\mathbb E[X - \theta \mathbb E X]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]} = \frac{(1-\theta)^2 \mathbb E[X]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof follows if you replace $\lambda = \theta EX$ in the following [post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124433/show-that-px-lambda-geq-fracex-lambda2ex2?rq=1)